# What is the meaning of a trailing hyphen in this crontab command?

Tags: bash, cron

I was looking into how to programmatically add a cronjob, and came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4880290/5579099) which advises using the following one liner:

```bash
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "*/5 * * * * /path/to/job -with args") | crontab -
```

What does the trailing `-` mean when provided to `crontab` here?

There's nothing in the man pages of `crontab` or `cron` about it as far as I can tell, and my research thus far has only told me that a `-` character is used in syntax to move file descriptors, has a special meaning for here documents, and that `$-` expands to the currently enabled shell options.

What is the trailing `-` doing here for `crontab` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manpage of `crontab`

> SYNOPSIS
>
> `crontab [ -u user ] file`
>
> ...
>
> The first form of this command is used to install a new crontab from some named file or standard input if the pseudo-filename `-` is given.

So, the `-` instructs `crontab` to create the crontab entry from the output of the preceding command, which is piped to the `stdin` of the `crontab` command via the `|` operator.

Comment: Huh, I'm running CentOS 7.9 with cronie version 1.4.11-23, and this section of the manpage just is not there. Thanks for the help though !

Comment: @Pacopenguin it may be then that your version of `crontab` does not support this syntax